# -Zsys and -Zomf in dos emx

Tags: gcc, dos

What exactly is the function of the -Zsys and -Zomf flags when compiling with emx-gcc on dos? Do they always have to be used together to compile a program? I'm trying to compile a cl utility for Dos real mode, and the emxdev documentation is rather terse on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the `-Zsys` nor the `-Zomf` options are useful when using emx-gcc to create MS-DOS programs. Executables produced with these options will only run under OS/2. The `-Zomf` tell the compiler to convert the object files into OMF format and use the OS/2 linker to create executables. The `-Zsys` option meant to be used with the `-Zomf` option and additionally tells the compiler to link with the OS/2 system call library instead of the emx library.

You might want to consider using [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) instead, as its still maintained and supported.

Comment: Now it all makes sense.